# Call ASP.NET post route from other C# server-side controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is for a web application that has a C# back-end. The way it is architected I am not able to just import one of these classes to the other to call the method directly. Unfortunately, we have something going wrong with our build process, so I am unable to debug this code, so I'm hoping to nail it in as few iterations as possible.

In one controller we have this method:

```
    [Route("api/uploadFile/{id}")]
    [HttpPost]
    [CustomAuthorize]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Description = "File upload successful")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Error uploading file")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostFile(int id, [FromUri]bool replace=false)
    {
        //code to put the file in the database;
    }
```

and I need to figure out how to call that from a different controller. These two controllers are in two completely separate projects and have no knowledge of each other.

I've tried a handful of variations of the following, but it each change takes about 8 mins in a build process so I didn't want to just hack on it anymore:

```
    HttpClient htc = new HttpClient();
    HttpContent content = new StreamContent(myfile);
    var response = await htc.PostAsync(this.Url.Content("~/api/uploadFile/9992"),  content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Can you add a reference to that project temporarily to do you test or will that create a circular reference?

Comment: Put your code to put the file in the database should be in a separate class in a data access layer class library that both routes would call. The controller is not the correct layer of abstraction for this.

Comment: @SamMarion I could probably get away with adding it temporarily, but it would be more effort than what it's worth. It will eventually need to be reseparated and I know that the PostFile method works correctly when called from the client, I just can't figure out how to call it server-side.

Comment: @Kell It is setup like that actually, I just didn't bother to explain in detail how it works because it is completely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's all executing on the same server reflection could work.

First I would move the post file logic out into a separate method.

Then get a reference to the assembly using from there we just do this:

```
Assembly assm = Assembly.Load("AssemblyName");
object instance = assm.CreateInstance("ClassName");
object retVal = instance.GetType().GetMethod("NewMethod").Invoke(instance, null);
```